# How do I remove newline in front of lower-case characters in sed?

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a text file with about 5,000 lines. I want to remove the lines in front of the lower-case characters, so that

```
Now is the time for
all good men
The quick brown fox
jumped over
```

Becomes:

```
Now is the time for all good men
The quick brown fox jumped over
```

Answer (score 4):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. What you are trying to do is not a simple substitution on an individual line and so you should not be considering using sed. Just use awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^[[:upper:]]/?ors:OFS), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
Now is the time for all good men
The quick brown fox jumped over
```

The above will work efficiently, portably, and robustly with any awk on any UNIX system.

Comment: This one seems to be a shorter alternative... `awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/^[[:upper:]]/?OFS:ORS)}'`

Comment: That would print a trailing blank character and no terminating newline if a line that starts with upper case wasn't followed by a line that starts with lower.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR>1 && /^[[:upper:]]/{print ""} {printf "%s%s", $0, OFS} END{print ""}' file
```

And a `perl`:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "\n" if $.>1 && /^[[:upper:]]/; s/\R/ /; print; END{print "\n"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed ':a;N;/\n\([[:lower:]]\)/!ba;s// \1/' file
```

Posixly correct would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed ':a;N;/'$'\n''\([[:lower:]]\)/!ba;s// \1/' file
```

since `\n` isn't defined as an escape sequence by POSIX.

Comment: GNU sed only that...

Comment: What do you think is GNU specific here?

Comment: The use of `\n`. POSIX `sed` does not support `\n` as freely (Specifically, only as a literal embedded in pattern space). Tried yours with `gsed` and POSIX `sed` -- only `gsed` worked. Otherwise, great.

Comment: @dawg Oh yes, you are right! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured it out

```
enter code here`sed ':a;N;/\n[a-z]/s/\n/ /;ta;P;D' intput.txt > output.txt
```